# React Native Android error after trying to install expo-modules in bare react native app. using manual installations

Tags: android, react-native, expo

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
216 actionable tasks: 209 executed, 7 up-to-date
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel

Comment: Is there are any solution?

Comment: @sanjeev this was fixed in the last expo update, check the docs and use the automatic installation